# How can I place the left half of every odd page next to the right half of every even page?

Tags: pgffor

What I want to achieve is to check the vertical spacing of my resulting PDF. To do this I think it is convenient to place two halfs of every front and rear (so odd and next even) page onto one page and see if they match each other. O was succesful achieving this with `textpos` and trimming/clipping, but I struggle to automate it with `pgffor`. How can I use the variables `\x`  and `\y` to reference the page in the `\includegraphics` command?

```
\documentclass[paper=155mm:230mm]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using \x+1] in {1,3,...,7} {%
\newpage
\begin{textblock*}{77.5mm}[0,0](0mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\x,trim=7.4mm 10mm 84.9mm 7.4mm,width=77.5mm,clip]{Input.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
\begin{textblock*}{77.5mm}[0,0](77.5mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\y,trim=84.9mm 10mm 7.4mm 7.4mm,width=77.5mm,clip]{Input.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
~
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can combine two pages into one using pdfpages.  Many pdf viewers have a two page at a time view option.  Or you could just  use showframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems the problem was, that the evaluation in the `\foreach` statement by default results in a floating point evaluation. So as we need an integer for the page to reference, we can as `\foreach` to to calculate one by saying `int(\x+1)` or the complete code:

```
\documentclass[paper=155mm:230mm]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x+1)] in {1,3,...,7}{
\newpage
\begin{textblock*}{77.5mm}[0,0](0mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\x,trim=7.4mm 10mm 84.9mm 7.4mm,width=77.5mm,clip]{Input.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
\begin{textblock*}{77.5mm}[0,0](77.5mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\y,trim=84.9mm 10mm 7.4mm 7.4mm,width=77.5mm,clip]{Input.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
~
}
\end{document}
```